# Azure Membership account access issue

Tags: c#, azure

I deployed my MVC application on the WindowsAzure staging environment. I used universal provider for membership. But i am little bit confused.

My confusion is that i created some accounts on my local machine now after deployment when i am trying to access those accounts in cloud, i got error message incorrect  username or password but if i am accessing those accounts from my local machine, then there was no error message. I did`nt change the connection string. Can anybody please explain me the concept or give me some reference link ?

Comment: Does your connection string point to a SQL Azure database or to somewhere else? Perhaps to a local database in app_data?

Answer (score 1):

As you asked for concept on how it works, i can explain it. When you are using ASP.NET Universal Providers in your MVC app, there must a database where it can be configured. In most cases SQLExpress is the local database used by Universal Providers to store the membership details.

Now when you deploy your application to Windows Azure as Cloud Service there is no local database configured so your default configuration to Universal Providers will not work. The best way to solve this problem is to configure your MVC application universal providers to use SQL Database even when you are testing locally. Once local tests are completed and your deploy your application to Windows Azure, because your application is still pointing to SQL Database, it will work without any problem (considering you have configured SQL Database properly).

This particular [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) shows different connection strings used in MVC application to connect with SQLExpress or SQL Database so you can use it to modify your SQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set an explicit `<machineKey>` in your `web.config`. That key is used for a number of things relating to sessions and membership (like cookies and passwords). If you don't specify the key explicitly, Windows Azure chooses one for you on each deployment, which will invalidate existing auth cookies and stored passwords.